# How to exclude some property from object in ASP.NET WebApi

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

If I have an object that I return from WebApi, is it possible to mark one of the properties as  hidden ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use:

```
[JsonIgnore]
[XmlIgnore]
```

These will hide your property from both kinds of serialization.
I have always tried to mix both in a single class but `JSonIgnoreAtrribute` is a sealed class and does not leave us with a seamless integration option.

So the straight forward way is to add both attributes on your ignorable property.